# What is correct "source path directory" for AWS Amplify for Angular?

Tags: aws-amplify

During amplify init there is a question: "Source path directory". Default is "/". Project is Angular. Should it be set to "/" or should it be set to "src"?

Comment: It must set to "/"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a standard project with the [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io) it will be src if you created your project with `ng new app`.